# Magento2.3 files permissions inside docker container (ubuntu)

Tags: magento2, docker, ubuntu

i am beginner in Magento 2.3, and i encountred an issue when i tried to enable my **first custom module**: 
     `bin/magento module:enable Mageplaza_HelloWorld`

I'm using docker apache container to run my Magento 2 and ubuto for OS, Can you please let me know how to **change permissions inside docker apache container**This is my issue in the image below:

[image]

Comment: Please set 777 permission to var/ pub/ and generated/ directories. and then check again

Comment: @KishanSavaliya : I can't change permissions inside my docker container : when i run  `chmod 777 var`  
==> _chmod: changing permissions of 'var': Operation not permitted_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connect to your docker container as root and change permissions to folders var/ pub/ and generated so that php process can create/delete files it them.

```
docker exec -it -u root magento23_apache bash
```

Note: Don't run ./bin/magento from root user.

Comment: I connected from root user and i sat 777 permission to (var/,generated/,pub/) then changed its  owner:groupe with chmod command. Thank's it works :) !!!